# sparse matrix in EIGEN Ram consuption

Tags: c++, ram, eigen

first I fill the spase matrix :

```
  SparseMatrix<double> matA;
```

, with my count 600*10 000 take about 48 MB and + indexes in int 24 MB= 72 MB so why its in ANdroid device 2 times bigger?-in the, So the Eigen uses some special tree-M structures, or where is the problem?

And for example: A*A' ..this result product of this proceees takes in this case same 2 times bigger ram consuption...

Comment: please proof-read your question. It is very difficult to understand. Also, please give the number of rows, columns, and non-zeros (matA.nonZeros()).

Comment: rows=524 000 ,cols=600, non zeros=10 000 in each column;

Answer (score 0):

Your estimation seems correct, however if you inserted elements with the insert() function, then you have to call `.compress()` to release the automatically preallocated memory. Properly reserving room for each column should prevent the allocation of extra memory: `A.reserve(VectorXi::Constant(600,10000));`

Comment: insertBack i use and finalize(); but there is now problem, but after this filling the matrix have bigger size, but maybe depends on android ram service. or i dont know, exist way how to find out, the actual sze of this matrixx?

Comment: Are you sure it is only the size of this matrix object or does there exist any other array/object?

Comment: matA is in my code only one, but if its in  the some another app or android in the native layer---i Dont know